# Refactor AngularJs routing configuration

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, resolve

I have the following routing configuration with the several URL that has to be resolved based on the value on some function. Here the code-snippet:

```
 $routeProvider
            .when('/url_with_restrictions', {
                templateUrl: '/pages/private/add_entity/add_gasstation.html',
                controller: 'ControllerName',
                // restrict angularjs routing
                resolve: {
                    validate: functionToBeInjected(){ 
                         var validateAccess = $q.defer();
                         return validateAccess.promise;
                    }
                }
        })
```

How can I define the function `functionToBeInjected()` and use it in every `resolve` for a controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You could just extract a function to set up routes

```
function addRoute(url, template, controller) {
  functionToBeInjected = ...
  $routeProvider
        .when(url, {
            templateUrl: template,
            controller: controller,
            // restrict angularjs routing
            resolve: {
                validate: functionToBeInjected(){ 
                     var validateAccess = $q.defer();
                     return validateAccess.promise;
                }
            }
    })
};
```